Help identify IC MS00W87.1
Please help me to identify IC component shown on the image. It reads 2405 MS00W87.1, found in 3-in-1 computer speaker with microphone device, model Y1812. I believe it is related to sound (amplifier?), as it is located near speaker, but can't find any specs.

The device, 3-in-1 computer speaker with microphone, model Y1812 looks like this:

